# pooled "stateless instances" VS "stateless singleton bean" in Java EE

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

What are the benefits in having a bunch of pooled **"stateless instances"** instead of one **"stateless singleton bean"** in Java-EE?

**Singleton Java-EE:**

```
@ApplicationScoped
public class MySingletonDAO {
// no global properties are shared
..
}
```

or an alternative stateless singleton bean:

```
@Singleton
@ConcurrencyManagement(ConcurrencyManagementType.BEAN)
public class MySingletonDAO {
// no global properties are shared
..
}
```

**Stateless Java-EE:**

```
@Stateless
public class MyStatelessDAO {
..
}
```

I cannot see any benefit in using a `@Stateless`-bean instead of a **"stateless singleton"**-bean. Are there any?

Comment: possible related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14464823/difference-between-stateless-and-singleton

Comment: @second I have red this and I cannot find any information why choosing Stateless instead of "stateless singleton". So it's only little related to this issue.

Comment: The concurrent usage should be a benefit, but you were probably aware of that already as you described it as a `bunch of pooled` objects.

Comment: "The concurrent usage" of stateless-bean is not a benefit because "(stateless) singletons" can also be accessed concurrently.

Comment: Sure, but in case you do some (albeit whacky) synchronisation there it won`t run as nicely. An example for that might be a global counting mechanism that is split across multiple instances.

Comment: "global counting mechanism that is split across multiple instances" ? Such cases are better done with `@javax.ejb.Singleton @ConcurrencyManagement(ConcurrencyManagementType.CONTAINER)` instead of `@Stateless`.